How can I do inverse Laplace of this transfer function to get the step response of the RLC circuit?


I have found this to be my transfer function for the circuit. I have tried doing partial fraction decomposition, but I end up with an s on top which I don't understand what to do with.

Reverse Laplace tables can be found on the net. Might the s on top be something to do with that you forgot to multiply the above formula by the step input (1/s) before taking partial fractions. Show you working please.

Calculation of the transfer function of the given network, the impulse response and the step response:

